# How is recursive function implemented in functional languages?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, interpreter, compiler-construction

Consider a following recursive function top-level binding:

```
let f = (a => f a);
```

(where `arg => expr` is a lambda expression)

To define `f` in the global environment, first we have to evaluate value of the `f`, namely `a => f a`. But since `f` isn't defined yet, expression `a => f a` would cause an error.

How do functional language interpreters/compilers handle this problem?

Comment: "*To define f in the global environment, first we have to evaluate value of the f*" - No, all we need to do is declare the name `f`. We do not need to evaluate anything.

Comment: Why do you think this would be a problem in functional languages only? Wouldn't compiling a recursive function in an imperative language be just the same?

Comment: @Bergi Thank you. What do you mean by *declaring the name*? When do we evaluate the value of `f`?

Comment: We need the value of `f` only when the `f` function is actually called. By "declaring" I mean reserving a place in memory that can be *referenced* (read: an object), but we don't need to initialise it to refer to it.